# Unresolved Reference to sys.objects reported from Data Migration Assistant assessment for move to Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, data-migration

We are migrating a new SQL Server 2017 DB to Azure. We ran the Microsoft Data Migration Assistant today in Assessment mode for moving from SQL Server to Azure SQL Database. We are trying to resolve 'unresolved reference to an object' blocker items. This should not count as a cross DB query. The view works fine in our local instance.

Under the AssessmentRecommendations section, there is this block:

```
{  "CompatibilityLevel": "CompatLevel140",
   "Category": "Compatibility",
   "Severity": "Error",
   "ChangeCategory": "MigrationBlocker",
   "RuleId": "71501",
   "Title": "Unresolved references found",
   "Impact": "One or more objects were found that contain unresolved references, which may block migration to Azure SQL Database.",
   "Recommendation": "Address the unresolved references reported in \"Object details\" section.",
              "MoreInfo": "",
              "ImpactedObjects": See below... }
```

For the `dbo.VW_BUILD_PARAMETERS` stored procedure, there are the following reported issues under ImpactedObjects:

```
        {
          "Name": "dbo.VW_BUILD_PARAMETERS.IsOutPutParameter",
          "ObjectType": "Computed Column",
          "ImpactDetail": "Computed Column: [dbo].[VW_BUILD_PARAMETERS].[IsOutPutParameter] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [sys].[objects].[P]::[is_output], [sys].[parameters].[is_output] or [sys].[parameters].[P]::[is_output]. For more details, please see: Line 18, Column 1.",
          "SuggestedFixes": []
        },
        {
          "Name": "dbo.VW_BUILD_PARAMETERS.ObjectName",
          "ObjectType": "Computed Column",
          "ImpactDetail": "Computed Column: [dbo].[VW_BUILD_PARAMETERS].[ObjectName] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [sys].[objects].[Name], [sys].[objects].[SO]::[Name] or [sys].[parameters].[SO]::[Name]. For more details, please see: Line 5, Column 8.",
          "SuggestedFixes": []
        },
        {
          "Name": "dbo.VW_BUILD_PARAMETERS.ParameterOrder",
          "ObjectType": "Computed Column",
          "ImpactDetail": "Computed Column: [dbo].[VW_BUILD_PARAMETERS].[ParameterOrder] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [sys].[objects].[P]::[parameter_id], [sys].[parameters].[P]::[parameter_id] or [sys].[parameters].[parameter_id]. For more details, please see: Line 14, Column 1.",
          "SuggestedFixes": []
        },
```

Here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VW_BUILD_PARAMETERS]
AS
SELECT SO.Name AS [ObjectName],
  CASE SO.Type_Desc 
    WHEN 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'
    THEN 'Procedure'
    WHEN 'SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION'
    THEN 'Function'
    WHEN 'SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION'
    THEN 'Function'
  END AS [ObjectType],
  P.parameter_id AS ParameterOrder,
  REPLACE( P.name, '@','') AS ParameterName,
  UPPER(TYPE_NAME(P.system_type_id)) AS ParameterType,
  CASE 
    WHEN TYPE_NAME(P.user_type_id) = 'varchar' 
    THEN CAST(P.max_length AS INT) 
  END AS MaximumCharacterLength,
  P.is_output AS [IsOutPutParameter]
FROM sys.objects AS SO
INNER JOIN sys.parameters AS P 
   ON SO.OBJECT_ID = P.OBJECT_ID
WHERE SO.type IN ('P','FN','IF')
AND P.parameter_id > 0
```

I don't see how `'P.parameter_id AS ParameterOrder'` is unresolved among:

> `[sys].[objects].[P]::[parameter_id]`  - Why would it try to do P alias on sys.objects? There is no sys.objects.parameter_id.
>
> `[sys].[parameters].[P]::[parameter_id]`  - Seems like this should be the match
>
> `[sys].[parameters].[parameter_id]`   - Why would it not match the P alias

Comment: The only pattern I can see is that the ImpactedObjects issues are mostly against select column statements where we are not performing some action, no CASE/REPLACE/UPPER.  We have a second stored procedure, also working with INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables that has similar issues, around the select of columns where no action is taking place on the selected field.

Comment: I don't know why but this seemed to fix this problem.  Change 'P.parameter_id AS ParameterOrder' to 'CAST(P.parameter_id as int) AS ParameterOrder,'  I would love to know why.